# Execute a sampler each minute in Jmeter inside a thread

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I have a thread calling different http sampler inside it. Since its sequentially called, every sample must be executed one after another.

I've searched for a way to execute a sample each minute concurrently inside this thread with no success.

I know I could start another thread, but it won't do it, as some information passed each minute must be feeded by the thread where it is located.

I must be missing something obvious but I didn't found any information related to that on the Jmeter website.

Comment: Have you heard about http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/InterThreadCommunication ?